# MySQL database naming convention?

Tags: mysql, naming-convention

Is there any convention for database names in MySQL/MariaDB? I've searched Google and this Stack Exchange and haven't been able to find anything. Not even a "Nope, there's no official convention." Is there a standard, or is this something that's decided on a case-by-case basis?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Database names are completely up to the person creating them.  Having said that, it makes sense to use *some kind* of sane naming convention.

Don't use reserved keywords, don't put spaces in the name, etc.  Essentially, follow the [MySQL Documentation for identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html), and add a little common sense that applies to your environment.

Answer (score 4):

On beyond the database names...

Don't prefix table names with the database name.

Don't prefix column names with the table name.  A possible exception is `id` --> `foo_id` to be consistent with references to it in other tables.

Why?  Too much clutter.  And, when `JOINing`, you should use table names (or aliases) on *every* column name to make it clear what table the column comes from.

The column name `id` should be `INT` (of some size), `UNSIGNED`, `AUTO_INCREMENT`, and (usually) the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Other column names should be 'meaningful' and not misleading.